# How to set file permissions when mounting TrueCrypt file container in OS X

Tags: macos, truecrypt

I have a TrueCrypt file container (FAT filesystem) containing a number of SSH private key files.

I want to be able to add these private keys to my SSH keychain, however I'm having trouble mounting the encrypted file container with the correct permissions in OS X.

```
$ truecrypt --text -m ro /Users/admin/Secure.truecrypt /Volumes/TrueCrypt
```

I'm passing the `ro` (readonly) mount options as directed by the man pages, however `/Volumes/TrueCrypt` (and all of the files within it) are mounted with world read-write-execute permissions:

```
$ ls -la /Volumes/TrueCrypt/
drwxrwxrwx@ 1 admin   staff  16384 31 Dec  1979 .
drwxrwxrwt@ 6 root    admin    204 14 Oct 13:56 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 admin   staff   1766  9 Oct 10:28 id_rsa.rsa
-rwxrwxrwx  1 admin   staff    672  6 Jul  2012 org_rsa.rsa
```

This means `ssh-add` ignores the keys saying the permissions are too open.

https://serverfault.com/a/82282 suggests defining `/etc/fstab` as a workaround, however as far as I'm aware I can't use `fstab` here as I'm using a TrueCrypt file container instead of a volume. (I'd welcome correction on this if I'm mistaken...)

How can I access these key files with the correct permissions (600) on OS X?

Answer (score 0):

Your `truecrypt` command will mount your file *as a volume*, so the serverfault solution is stil applicable.